# How to implement re-sizing a cardview programatically in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout

Hi every one I am facing an issue while trying to expand the height of card view programatically in kotlin. I have tried to fix this by following some web resources, but those failed.

```
 val layout = findViewById<CardView>(R.id.listGroupCardView)
    val params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = layout.layoutParams
    params.height = 100
    layout.layoutParams = params
```

Resulting in "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference"

My code snippets are:

```
deviceHeight in 1800..2000 -> {
            Log.d(tag, "Inside setUIComponents device height is $deviceHeight")

            enterUniqueCode.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16F)
            enterUniqueCode.height= 300
            bearingImg.layoutParams.width = 350
            bearingImg.layoutParams.height= 350
            bearingImg.updatePadding(top=15)
            etBarcode.height= 70
            indicator.updatePadding(top=0)
            etBarcode.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25F)

            val param = etBarcode.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
            param.setMargins(0,45,0,7)
            etBarcode.layoutParams = param

            //etBarcode.updatePadding(top = 25)
            cvSubmit.layoutParams.height= 150
            btnSubmit.layoutParams.height= 150
            Log.d(tag, "btnSubmit.height is : ${btnSubmit.height}")
            btnSubmit.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25F)
            llUniqueCode.layoutParams.height= 250
            totalEarningImage.layoutParams.width= 150
            totalEarningImage.layoutParams.height= 150
            totalEarnings.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15F)
            tvTotalPointsEarned.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15F)
            llTotalEarnings.layoutParams.height = 150
            productCatalogueImage.layoutParams.height = 150
            productCatalogueImage.layoutParams.width = 150
            productCatalogueImage.updatePadding(top=2)
            transactionHistory.layoutParams.height = 150
            transactionHistory.layoutParams.width = 150
            transactionHistory.updatePadding(top=2)
            referAFriend.layoutParams.height = 150
            referAFriend.layoutParams.width = 150
            referAFriend.updatePadding(top=2)
            llBearing.updatePadding(top=12)
        }
```

Here, before the brace ends, I have to resize the height of cardview of the layout which is list_group.xml, in this case here, And the list_group.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listGroupCardView"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_48"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listGroup"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        
        <ImageView>
            ............
        </ImageView>

        <TextView>
            ............
        </TextView>
   </LinearLayout>
   </CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I need help to figure out how to re-size this list_group's cardview programatically using kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Set new `layout params` to the layout ,because the current `layout params` is `null`

```kotlin
val layout = findViewById<CardView>(R.id.listGroupCardView)
val params = ViewGroup.LayoutParams (
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    100
)
layout.layoutParams = params
```